# Why an installed app is not listed by Ms Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to upgrade an app which belongs to a chat. If the app is not installed, below code successfully install it:

```
await graph.Chats["19:7f...3@thread.v2"].InstalledApps
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(teamsAppInstallation);
```

But once the app is added, below code shows zero entries:

```
var installedApps = await graph.Chats["19:7f...3@thread.v2"].InstalledApps.Request().GetAsync();
```

I was expecting to see my app there. My target is to call Upgrade() for the app, because it should allow me to add ConversationReferences in one of the event functions (e.g. OnTurnAsync), that will allow me to send [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) to the chat. Am I doing something wrong?
Permissions for an application are set:

> TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForChat.All 
> TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser.All

The authentication with the Graph API is done successfully, as I can create a chat, list channels etc.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
> data:
> grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={ MS_APP_ID_ENC }&client_secret={ MS_APP_PASS_ENC }&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default

I was adding the app to the chat both manually and with C# request:

```
var teamsAppInstallation = new TeamsAppInstallation {
AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {
        "teamsApp@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/0c...68/"}
    }
};
var installedApp = await graph.Chats["19:7f...3@thread.v2"].InstalledApps.  Request().AddAsync(teamsAppInstallation);
```

And the app was added. It can be used in the chat.

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will update you soon.

Comment: Could you please share repro steps or any ref. so that we can try it out at our end?

Comment: I added more info to the question, but steps are pretty simple... 1. Get the token 2. Install an app in a group chat (either way: manually in Teams or in C# request). 3. Send a GET request to list the installed apps

Comment: Not able to reproduce issue but heard same issue from other developer as well. High level, Get installed apps API is not returning results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I've used wrong application permissions. Even though *TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForChat.Al* is listed in the docs, I needed to add *TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForChat.All* to make it working.